# How to specify Regexp options using Regexp.union

Tags: ruby, regex, syntax

In "[How do I removing URLs from text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243120/how-do-i-removing-urls-from-text)" the following code is suggested:

```
require 'uri'
#...
schemes_regex = /^(?:#{ URI.scheme_list.keys.join('|') })/i
#...
```

I tried to improve this to:

```
schemes_regex = Regexp.union(URI.scheme_list.keys)
```

but I can't figure out how the `IGNORECASE` option (`i`) should be specified.

Comment: Since I wrote that code... the reason I used interpolation the way I did is to simplify making a case-insensitive regex. Ruby's `Regex.union` needs to allow more flexibility, such as the normal Regex constants like `IGNORECASE` but since it doesn't, I chose to interpolate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to pass option arguments to `Regexp.union` like that. You could of course specify them after the union operation:

```
require 'uri'

Regexp.new(Regexp.union(URI.scheme_list.keys).source, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
# => /FTP|HTTP|HTTPS|LDAP|LDAPS|MAILTO/i
```

Comment: I've used this before, but it results in some code-smell as far as I'm concerned, because we create a Regexp object, then convert it to its source string, then recompile it into another Regexp object. That's why I went with a simple `join('|')` from the OP's referenced answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
schemes_regex = Regexp.union(
  *URI.scheme_list.keys
  .map{|s| Regexp.new(s, Regexp::IGNORECASE)}
)
```

Comment: (Six years later...) `Regexp.union` will take an array as an argument, so the splat is unnecessary. Great answer, tho.

Answer (score 2):

same as sawa's response but it is looking for scheme to be at the beginning of string:

```
Regexp.union(*URI.scheme_list.keys.map {|s| /\A#{s}/i })
```

### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=how-to-specify-regexp-options-using-regexp-union.rb&run=true)

Comment: `\A` or `^` is a moot point in the comparison of the resulting regex with the strings being tested. The OP's question is out of context with the original need for testing. Refer to the original question to see why.